# Guardar un registro sin posibilidad de error while true, try createview

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Espero no ser un poco paranoica pero estoy tratando de hacer que cuando exista un registro o número de cliente igual el próximo registro sea diferente al anterior, el motivo por el que lo hago así es porque va haber mucha mucha gente capturando datos al mismo tiempo todos los días y lo que no quiero que les arroje un error 404 o algo por el estilo sino todo lo contrario, en caso de que ya exista un registro en la base de datos volver a intentar y volver a internar y volver a intentar.

Este es un ejemplo que necesito concluir para terminar bien mi script, obvio antes hace una petición a la base de datos para verificar el último registro.

Ya sé que es posible hacerlo con vistas basadas en funciones pero en este momento estoy probando vistas basadas en clases, llevo varias horas con esto. Cualquier ayuda es muy importante para mí.

Gracias chicos.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Empresa(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    numero = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
```

views.py

```
from dataclasses import field
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import *

from aplicacion.models import Empresa

# Create your views here.

class CrearEmpresa(CreateView):
    model = Empresa
    template_name = 'crearempresa.html'
    success_url  = '/crear/'
    fields = ['nombre', 'numero']

    valor = 0
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        x = form.save(commit=False)
        x.numero = self.valor

        while True:
            try:
                x.save()
                return super().form_valid(form)
                break
            
            except:
                self.valor = self.valor + 1
                pass
```

Comment: Según entiendo, si 2 usuarios están registrando la empresa "ACME Inc.", a una le corresponderá el número `X` y a otra le corresponderá `X + 1`. ¿Significa que habrá 2 registros para la misma "ACME Inc."? No parece una forma muy adecuada de registro.

Comment: IMHO las vistas basadas en clases son mi enfoque preferido. Aprovecho para comentarte que utilizar el parámetro `form_class` también conseguirá hacer tu código mucho más legible y "mantenible" . Con respecto a tu duda, podrías utilizar `self.valor = Empresa.objects.all().order_by('numero').last().numero + 1`, controlando en algún sitio que haya alguna empresa, claro está.

Comment: Al haber tanta gente registrando al mismo tiempo puede  haber la posibilidad de guardar al mismo tiempo ocasionando que algún cliente le arroje un error lo que ocasionaría volver a llenar el formulario, eso es lo que trato de evitar.